# C# using reflection entity framework sum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

For a certain column name I want to calculate the SUM. I just found out how to use reflection but don't know if i'm doing it the right way..

```
string columnName = "days";
ObjectQuery<TableX> objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TableX>();

Func<TDomainEntity, object> fieldGetter;
var type = typeof(TDomainEntity);
var prop = type.GetProperty(columnName);
fieldGetter = e => prop.GetValue(e,null);

//this wouldn't work because the fieldGetter should be Func<TDomainEntity, decimal> and not object
var total = objectSet.Sum(fieldGetter);
```

I can't get this working because the fieldgetter should be of the type decimal but the the type.GetProperty will fail and casting it didn't work. So what am I missing or is there another way?
I could make a giant switch statement for the columnname but that's not nice is it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the type should be `decimal`, then tell that to the getter:

```
Func<TDomainEntity, decimal> fieldGetter = e => (decimal)prop.GetValue(e,null);
```

Which should then work with LINQ-to-Objects as:

```
var total = objectSet.Sum(fieldGetter);
```

Note that if you intend to use LINQ-to-EF, you'll have to construct an expression tree instead:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDomainEntity));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDomainEntity, decimal>>(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(p, columnName), p);
var total = query.Sum(lambda);
```

Of course, you can use that approach *either way*:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDomainEntity));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDomainEntity, decimal>>(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(p, columnName), p);
var total = objectSet.Sum(lambda.Compile());
```

Comment: The cast to decimal gives an exception: {"Specified cast is not valid."}

Comment: @RubenR then the property isn't a `decimal`